# Non tinted text on pcb altium

Tags: altium

I added a string in PCB Editor and it is on Top Layer, which is good. But when viewing in 3D, its tinted. Its behind the color layer and not appearing clearly as it should like pads(the carbon part).

I couldn't find any setting to remove its region from color layer. How can I make it appear clear ?

Edit: added screenshot
[image]

[image: prop]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're placing text on the top copper layer, there will be soldermask over the copper, which I *think* is what you're seeing.

If you want to leave the soldermask off the copper, you actually place a pour/polygon on the soldermask layer. The soldermask is a *negative* layer, so where you draw things on the soldermaks layer, it will be *removed*.

You may need to enable the soldermask in the 2D view before you can draw on the layer, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>m</kbd> in the PCB view will open the relevant dialog, and then check the entry under "Mask Layers" for "Top Solder".

Comment: I created 2 instances of same text, overlapping each other. One is on top layer, which is copper one and another one is on Top Soldier. It working good now. I tried same thing before but it wasn't appearing copper. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You placed the text on Top Layer, which is the top copper layer.

Your screenshot shows solder mask covering your text. You need to place a feature on the solder mask layer to remove solder mask over your text if you want it to be visible. Solder mask is a negative layer, so features placed on this layer in your design are areas where solder mask will not be present.

Once you do that, at least for the default 3D view settings (which it doesn't look like you're using), Top Layer copper will render as yellow or gold. If you want it to render in a different color you probably need to adjust settings for the 3D viewer, not for the text itself.

If you want your text to show like the "P1" in your screenshot, you need to put it on the Top Overlay layer, not Top Layer. This will put it in the silkscreen, which is an ink layer on top of the solder mask, instead of a copper layer beneath the solder mask.

Answer (score 0):

Mate, you've got the highlighting thing turned on. Down the bottom right is a "clear" button which clears all the selected/highlighted layers and returns everything to proper colour.

EDIT: The Photon is right, it's the Top Layer being copper, you wanted Top Overlay layer for the string object.

Comment: I tried to clear, nothing changed. I added a screenshot.

Comment: @xmenW.K. are you 110% sure it's on Top Layer? It may also have some random custom colour added to it which overrides the Layer colour scheme, check the object parameters.

Comment: Added another screenshot.

Comment: @xmenW.K. make the font truetype.

Comment: There could also be something funky with your 3D layers/view configuration.. but it's strange how it's only doing the free primitive text/string object

Comment: @KyranF, because the "test" text is on Top Layer (copper) covered with soldermask, and the designator (P1) is on silkscreen so it's not covered with soldermask.

Comment: @ThePhoton you are right!! Top Layer is copper! It should be on Top Overlay! how silly.